# Condensing python lists with the same output

Tags: python, performance

I'm a novice trying to be efficient

```
if age >= 35:
    age_val = True
else:
    age_val = False

if born == "yes" or "Yes":
    born_val = True
else:
    born_val = False

if resident >= 14:
    res_val = True
else:
    res_val = False
```

As you can see, all of these checks have the same output. Is there a way I can condense the if/else statements to look something like this?

```
if age >= 35, born == "yes" or "Yes, resident >= 41:
     age_val, born_val, res_val = True
else:
     age_val, born_val, res_val = True
```

I know that isn't how python works, but maybe it has something similar?

Comment: you can use `age_val = True if age>=35 else False`

Comment: @OsmanMamun Or `age_val = age >= 35`.

Comment: I always forget the implicit truthiness of python variables

Comment: @OsmanMamun That's not the point here. The `>=` operator returns `True` or `False` directly.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about *performance*. I think what you really are looking for is clarity.

Firstly, whenever you see:

```
if condition:
    result = True
else:
    result = False
```

you can replace it with:

```
result = condition
```

So, for instance,

```
if age >= 35:
    age_val = True
else:
    age_val = False
```

becomes

```
age_val = age >= 35
```

Doing the same for the rest gives:

```
age_val = age >= 35
born_val = born == "yes" or born == "Yes"
res_val = resident >= 14
```

But why are we calling these `_val`s? Better would be to prefix with `is_`:

```
is_old_enough = age >= 35
is_born = born == "yes" or born == "Yes"
is_long_term_resident = resident >= 14
```

And then:

```
meets_criteria = (
    is_old_enough and
    is_born and
    is_long_term_resident
)

if meets_criteria:
    print("35+ years old resident of over 14 years was born at some point")
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks so much! I had another variable called valid is the equivalent to meets_criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a simple one liner;

`age_val, born_val, res_val = int(age) >= 35, born.lower() == 'yes', int(resident) >= 14`

Each conditional if is separated by a comma, and would be the equivalent to;

```
age_val = int(age) >= 35
born_val = born.lower() == 'yes'
res_val = int(resident) >= 14
```

Comment: Why would you want to write a one-liner?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I showed both examples as noted in the users example, they attempted to set 3 variables to true in one statement. `age_val, born_val, res_val = True` which is viable. Are there any outstanding negatives I've missed in regards to handling this on one line?

Comment: It makes it easier for me to think about code in larger sections. is that considered bad practice?

Comment: At the very least, it breaks PEP8's 80 char line-length restrictions, but the main issue is that it visually separates the variable assigned to from it's value, hurting readability. Most experienced devs almost always avoid this pattern unless it's for tuple unpacking: `pos = (1, 2); x, y = pos`. Or swapping: `a, b = b, a`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it okay for your needs to use a dictionary? If yes, you could do something like this:

```
data = {
    'age_val': age >= 35,
    'born_val': born == "yes",
    'res_val': resident >= 14
}
```

To retrieve data form such dict, you can use `get()`, so this `data.get('age_val')` would yield either `True` or `False`, depending on `resident` value.

Comment: `bool()` is casting `bool`s to `bool`s in this case.

Comment: Dictionaries keys can be accessed using index notation rather than method syntax: `data["age_val"]`

Comment: Yes, you're right - I've edited my answer. Regarding second comment - you're also right, but I prefer using `get()` because it guards you from `KeyError` and lets to provide fallback value.